# Alter Table Distribution (Azure Data warehouse)

Tags: t-sql, azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse

In rushing to get off work I ran a large insert on a new table that has a Round Robin distribution. I know it is unlikely, but is there a way to alter the table's distribution from Round Robin to a Hash Distribution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `ALTER TABLE` does not support changing the distribution of a table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.  The next best thing you could do is create a copy of the table using `CTAS`, drop the original table, then rename the new one, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.yourTable2
WITH (
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( yourColumn )
    )
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.yourTable
OPTION ( LABEL = 'CTAS: Change distribution on dbo.yourTable' );
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.yourTable
GO
RENAME OBJECT dbo.yourTable2 TO yourTable;
GO
```

Comment: is there a way to check a tables hash?

Comment: @m1nkeh No it's not exposed, but you can make the assumption all rows which have the same value have the same hash.  Can I ask why you might need to check the hash?

Comment: did it using the sys views in the end

Comment: Hi @m1nkeh can you share what you did?