# How to specify table distribution for auto create table in Azure DataFactory copy activity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I'm defining a copy activity pipeline in Azure DataFactory. The copy is from a parquet file in azure blobstorage to a table in Azure Synapse Analytics (former ADW).

The sink table in Synapse is always a new one, as it is defined dynamically by a parameter in the pipeline. For example: the sink table name is "`[schema].[some_prefix_{pipeline_string_parameter}]`".

Because of that, the sink table doesn't exist, it has to be created. To solve this, I'm using the "auto create table" option.

However, I also need to specify a specific distribution and persistence type. In my case, I want to define a hash distributed, heap table. How can I specify those configurations to the auto create table? As I understand, the default configs are CCI, round-robin, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned and as per the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory#supported-capabilities),

> Auto create table option in copy activity sink only gives default distribution i,e. `ROUND_ROBIN`.

You can raise a feature request about supporting other distributions [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

You can try the below possible methods as workarounds.

- If your **sink table schema is same for every time and if you know the schema**, then create table before copying the data. Give your desired distributions in the create table query. For executing the query before copy, you can use **Script activity** before copy activity (or) **pre-copy script** in the copy activity sink.

  [image]

  Pass your table name to the script from the pipeline parameter using ADF dynamic content or string interpolation.
- If your sink table schema is different every time, then after copy activity, create a **duplicate table** for your table with your desired distribution using `CTAS`. After creating duplicate table, drop your original table and rename it as original table. Go through the script provided in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44399586) by @[wBob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1527504/wbob) to do that.
  Here, you need to use the **Script activity** after copy activity to execute the script.